# What are the Output Variables from 'Analyze Particle'?

Tags: variables, particles

I need to use a specific value output by Analyze Particle in another part of my script.

The value I need is "Total Area", but I have no idea how to refer to it!

Do any of you know what variable name the "Total Area" value is stored under?

If it's differently referred to in different languages, let me say I'm using the native ImageJ Macro language.